# implementing $valid on readonly inputs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am validating a file upload.
I hid the file input and replaced it with a readonly input, into which I place the filename so it can be seen.
I want to display validation on this input, refelected from the file input.
However, $valid is not applicable on readonly inputs, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26555906/3548935).
How do I validate while keeping the functionality of being readonly?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, in css I can do `user-select: none;` which makes the input read only, while keeping validation.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16811266/3548935)

Comment: apparently, in chrome this css property doesn't work. I found a better solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17447050/3548935